# Como gravar o resultado do fetch em um txt e depois realizar o download?

Tags: php

Eu tenho seguinte código

```
$arquivo = fopen("descricao.txt","w");

while($dados = $cod_user->fetch_array()){ 
$bla = $dados['descricao'];
echo $dados['descricao'];

fwrite($arquivo,$bla);
```

Como escolho o diretório para salvar o arquivo e depois é realizado download?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "...  aparecer uma janela solicitando ao usuário o local?" ? Que local é esse? Do arquivo?

Comment: ao gerar o arquivo fazer download

Answer (score -1):

Não está muito claro seu intento, mas acho que o que você quer é buscar dados no banco e gravar em um arquivo txt no servidor. Então se é isso, a traquitana segue abaixo:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nomeDB");

$query = ("SELECT coluna FROM suaTabela");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $conteudo=$conteudo.chr(10).$row['n']."\r\n";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

$arquivo="linhas.txt";

file_put_contents($arquivo, $conteudo); 

/*
==========================================================================
Se o arquivo (linhas.txt) não existir, o arquivo é criado.
Do contrário, o arquivo é sobrescrito,
a não ser que o parâmetro FILE_APPEND seja definido e
nesse caso acrescenta os dados ao arquivo ao invés de sobrescrevê-lo.
Dessa forma acrescente esse parâmetro na linha file_put_contents, que
deverá ficar assim:  file_put_contents($arquivo, $conteudo, FILE_APPEND);
==========================================================================
*/

/* pode usar o trecho abaixo ao invés de file_put_contents
   $arq = fopen($arquivo,"w");
   fwrite($arq,$conteudo);
   fclose($arq);
*/

?>
```

E para fazer download do arquivo após ser gravado, acrescente esse trecho antes da tag de fechamento do PHP para que seja aberta a janela de opções de download.

```
header('Content-type: octet/stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$arquivo.'";'); 
readfile($arquivo);
```

file_put_contents http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php

fwrite   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php